# Calling ember component method from route?

Tags: ember.js

I have a route that looks like this: `http://localhost:4200/server/1/database/1/schema/1` and a tree-view component whose branches correspond to that url. So the above url shows the branches that are currently expanded. What I'd like to happen is that after page refresh with the above url in browser's address bar the branches should automatically expand. So how do I achieve that? Is there some `init` method on the component class that would let me get the information about current url therefore allowing me to programatically expand nodes on my tree view?

Comment: Components are isolated and have no idea where they are, you should pass what branch is open as a prop, something along the lines of `{{my-component branches='currentOpenBranch'}}`

Comment: Ok, but where can I get this `currentOpenBranch`? Should I pass it from controller?

Comment: Yup a controller property, you could always set it from the route since you might need the current route.

Comment: Ok, can you please show me an example (short code snippet), just to make sure I understand it correctly. You can post it as an answer. Also - a side question - I heard about this concept of routable components that would eliminate the need for keeping controllers. Are those available in current Ember.js version I'm using, which is 1.13.2? And if so, then how should I be using it in this scenario?

Comment: Routable components are coming in ember 2.0, they are currently [under development](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/10/run-up-to-two-oh.html#toc_routeable-components).